# Auto fitting text in a textbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Can't seem to find out to do this in either html or JS (or maybe even jquery?).

I have a text-box that echo's whatever is typed into it in an input box more down the page. This echo box needs to auto-fit to whatever text is inside it so that it doesn't have this huge white space spot after the text.

Any ideas how to auto-fit a input field to text that is inserted into it?

Comment: by "text-box" do you just mean something like a span?  `display: inline` doesn't work?

Comment: You need to clarify your question. What type of element do you want to "auto-fit"? `<input type="text"/>`? `<textarea>`? Something else entirely?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're looking for something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/ener3/

```
$("#in").keyup(function(){
  var tmp = $("<span>")
            .text(this.value)
            .css("font", $("#out").css("font"))
            .appendTo("body"),
      wid = tmp.width();
  tmp.remove();

  $("#out").val(this.value).width(wid);
});
```

where `#in` is the id of the input, and `#out` is the textbox you want to autosize.

You can add this to the head of the page like so:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    // paste the above code here
});
</script>
```

Make sure you put the script tag after your jQuery include:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

You can replace `1.8.3` with the version of jQuery you want to target. I wouldn't recommend using jQuery-latest to start as you'd have to account for potential deprecation where applicable.

Comment: It looks like jQuery is interpreting `#po[29439][458]` as something other than an ID. `$("input[id='po[29439][458]']").keyup...` works, but it might be better to do `$(document.getElementById("po[29439][458]").keyup...`

Comment: Well that comment doesn't make a lot of sense out of context.

Comment: That's it!
Now is there a way to include this on the top of an html page? As in make all this code work in one file and not a whole different jquery file? I don't have a whole lot of experience with jquery. I know CSS and JS can be added at the top of HTML using <script> and <style> tags.

Comment: Yea i thought it was the po name at first too but found out it may be something else. I don't think i am linking the jquery code correctly. I am trying to do it all within one file.